# Problema na alteração de dados no banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando alterar os dados do banco de dados, porém, ao enviar ele não apresenta mensagem de erro e o mesmo não altera os dados. O que pode está acontecendo?

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    //Slide
    $novo_slide1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['tituloslide']);
    $novo_subslide1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['subslide']);

    $novo_slide2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['tituloslide2']);
    $novo_subslide2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['subslide2']);

    $novo_slide3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['tituloslide3']);
    $novo_subslide3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['subslide3']);

    //Introduçao
    $novo_intro = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['intro']);
    $novo_introsub = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['introsub']);

    //Informativos
    $infor1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['infor1']);
    $textinfor1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['textinfor1']);

    $infor2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['infor2']);
    $textinfor2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['textinfor2']);

    $infor3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['infor3']);
    $textinfor3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['textinfor3']);

    //Serviços

    $serv1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['serv1']);
    $textserv = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['textserv']);

    //Lado Direito Horizontal
    $lado1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lado1']);
    $ladotext1 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['ladotext1']);


    $lado2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lado2']);
    $ladotext2 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['ladotext2']);

    $lado3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['lado3']);
    $ladotext3 = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['ladotext3']);

     //Frase
    $frase = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['frase']);
    $autor = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['autor']);

     //Pequeno Texto
    $smalltitle = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['smalltitle']);
    $smalltext = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['smalltext']);

     //Rede Social
    $facebook = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['facebook']);
    $instagram = mysqli_escape_string($connect,$_POST['instagram']);


    $result_update = "UPDATE editor SET slide1 = '$novo_slide1', slide2 = '$novo_slide2',slide3 = '$novo_slide3', subtext1 = '$novo_subslide1',subtext2 = '$novo_subslide2' ,subtext3 = '$novo_subslide3', titulo1 = '$novo_intro', subtitulo1 ='$novo_introsub', infor2 = '$infor2', textinfor2 = '$textinfor2', infor3 = '$infor3', textinfor3 = '$textinfor3',servicos = '$serv1', textservicos = '$textserv',iconsorriso = '$lado1', textsorriso = '$ladotext1', iconsujeira = '$lado2', textsujeira = '$ladotext2', iconpreco = '$lado3', textpreco = '$ladotext3', frase='$frase', autofrase = '$autor',fraseredesocial = '$smalltitle', textfraseredesocial = '$smalltext', linkfacebook = '$facebook', linkinstagra ='$instagram' WHERE id = '".$linha['id']."'";

     $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($connect,$result_update);

     echo "Adicionado";
 }
```

Comment: Está dando erro? Não retorna nada? Explique melhor o problema.

Comment: Eu coloco la as informaçoes pra ser alterada no banco de dados, porem nao esta alterando, nem dando erro, nao altera nada,

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser que ele nao esteja entrando no if, pois o

> $_POST['enviar']

não esteja setado.
Coloque um else, para ter certeza que esteja entrando e não fazendo nada.

Outra coisa, force a apresentação de erros com:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```